# PyQt5: clicked.connect not working with no errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Put simply my binding of signals to slots does not seem to be working, and I'm not getting any errors. Printing a message doesn't work in the function either.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QFont, QLinearGradient, QPainter, QPainterPath, QPalette, QPen)
from APM_ui import Ui_Window
import random, sys

print('... APM Loading ...')

uppercase = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
lowercase = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
PasswordFont = QFont('Lato', 11, QFont.Bold, True)

class Window(Ui_Window):
    def __init__(self, parent = None, name = None, fl = 0):
        Ui_Window.__init__(self, parent, name, fl)


        def createDefaultClicked(self):
            default = []
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            done = 0
            while True:
                if done!= 12:
                    random.shuffle(lowercase)
                    random.shuffle(uppercase)
                    decision = random.randint(0, 2)
                    if decision == 0:
                        default.append(random.randint(0, 9))
                        done += 1
                        continue
                    if decision == 1:
                        default.append(lowercase[0])
                        done += 1
                        continue
                    if decision == 2:
                        default.append(uppercase[0])
                        done += 1
                        continue
                if done == 12:
                    break
            self.defaultPWDisp.setFont(PasswordFont)
            defaultPassword = '{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(*default)
            self.defaultPWDisp.setText(_translate('Window', '<html><head/><body><p align=\'center\'>%s is your new password!</p></body></html>' % defaultPassword))


        def createSmallClicked(self):
            small = []
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            done = 0
            while True:
                if done!= 6:
                    random.shuffle(lowercase)
                    random.shuffle(uppercase)
                    decision = random.randint(0, 2)
                    if decision == 0:
                        small.append(random.randint(0, 9))
                        done += 1
                        continue
                    if decision == 1:
                        small.append(lowercase[0])
                        done += 1
                        continue
                    if decision == 2:
                        small.append(uppercase[0])
                        done += 1
                        continue
                if done == 6:
                    break
            self.smallPWDisp.setFont(PasswordFont)
            smallPassword = '{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(*small)
            self.smallPWDisp.setText(_translate('Window', '<html><head/><body><p align=\'center\'>%s is your new password!</p></body></html>' % smallPassword))

        def createTinyClicked(self):
            tiny = []
            _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
            done = 0
            while True:
                if done!= 6:
                    random.shuffle(lowercase)
                    random.shuffle(uppercase)
                    decision = random.randint(0, 2)
                    if decision == 0:
                        tiny.append(random.randint(0, 9))
                        done += 1
                        continue
                    if decision == 1:
                        tiny.append(lowercase[0])
                        done += 1
                        continue
                    if decision == 2:
                        tiny.append(uppercase[0])
                        done += 1
                        continue
                if done == 6:
                    break
            self.tinyPWDisp.setFont(PasswordFont)
            tinyPassword = '{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(*tiny)
            self.tinyPWDisp.setText(_translate('Window', '<html><head/><body><p align=\'center\'>%s is your new password!</p></body></html>' % tinyPassword))

        def createMidgetClicked(self):
            defaultPassword = []
            done = 0
            while True:
                if done!= 4:
                    random.shuffle(lowercase)
                    random.shuffle(uppercase)
                    decision = random.randint(0, 2)
                    if decision == 0:
                        defaultPassword.append(random.randint(0, 9))
                        done += 1
                        continue
                    if decision == 1:
                        defaultPassword.append(lowercase[0])
                        done += 1
                        continue
                    if decision == 2:
                        defaultPassword.append(uppercase[0])
                        done += 1
                        continue
                if done == 4:
                    break
            self.midgetPWDisp.setFont(PasswordFont)
            midgetPassword = '{}{}{}{}{}{}'.format(*midget)
            self.midgetPWDisp.setText(_translate('Window', '<html><head/><body><p align=\'center\'>%s is your new password!</p></body></html>' % midgetPassword))

# Look here! :P
    self.createDefault.clicked.connect(self.createDefaultClicked)   
    self.createSmall.clicked.connect(self.createSmallClicked)
    self.createTiny.clicked.connect(self.createTinyClicked)
    self.createMidget.clicked.connect(self.createMidgetClicked)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Window()
    ui.setupUi(window)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It is usually better to include the code as external services may not be available in the future. I  have included your code and changed the description to better fit what seems to be the problem. My change can be reverted if you do not like it.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem without use APM ui?

Comment: Your code seems to be incorrectly indented. Only your `clicked.connect` calls should be in the constructor (above all other methods), the other methods outside.

Comment: I've corrected your indenting, try the code now

Comment: I don't see your `class Window(Ui_Window)` has been create object in your code.

Comment: @Aleksandar Please do not correct code in the question. That is what are the answers for. That seems to be the problem which OP is having.

Comment: @Aleksander Sorry but your edits do not work as well :/

Answer (score 2):

I cannot run your code, but main issue seems to be incorrect indentation. Only your `clicked.connect` calls should be in the constructor (above all other methods), the other methods outside. See following runnable template for how should your code be structured:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.button1 = QPushButton("Test 1", self)
        self.button2 = QPushButton("Test 2", self)
        self.button3 = QPushButton("Test 3", self)

        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button1)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button2)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button3)

        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.on_button1)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.on_button2)
        self.button3.clicked.connect(self.on_button3)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_button1(self):
        print("Button #1")

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_button2(self):
        print("Button #2")

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_button3(self):
        print("Button #3")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Does my code work for you? If so, I would recommend creating just GUI alone with print statements (similar to this) and only when it works as expected start adding functionality. Your code as posted is hard to debug as we cannot run it as we are missing `APM_ui` module. Alternatively you can create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Creating a minimal runnable example which demonstrates the problem is a key when you need help with GUI.

Comment: Your code does work, I'll add APM_ui in original post shortly